# Is there any prime $p$ such that $6x^3 − p^2 − y^2 = 0$ has an integer solution?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, polynomial-congruences

I need to find whether there is any prime for which $6x^3 − p^2 − y^2 = 0$ has a integer solution.

For prime $p \neq 3$ ,considering this equation in modulo $3$ ,I find that there is no solution.

But for $3$ whether there is a solution or not I could not get this.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $p=3$ we have:

$$6x^3-9-y^2=0\implies 3\,|\,y$$

Writing $y=3Y$ we then have $$6x^3-9-9Y^2=0\implies 2x^3-3-3Y^2=0\implies 3\,|\,x$$
Writing $x=3X$ we then have $$54X^3-3-3Y^2=0\implies 18X^3-1-Y^2=0$$

And now working $\pmod 3$ shows that there are no solutions.

Comment: Typo.  Last line should read $18X^3$.  But this is of no concern.

Comment: @metoo  What do you mean?  Dividing by $3$ reduces the $18$ to a $6$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you cube $3X$ right?   So on the last line you'll have $54X^3-3-3Y^2=18X^3-1-Y^2.$  But still $18$ is zero $\pmod3.$  Nice solution.

Comment: @metoo  Oh, of course.  My blunder.  That's for pointing it out...I'll edit.